# How to securely get a key from a key server?

Tags: tls, certificates, key-server

In the installation procedure of Gentoo, there is a [step](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Media#Linux_based_verification) to check signature of the downloaded iso file. To do so, we first need to download the set of keys from a key server:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0xBB572E0E2D182910
```

However, when I first run this command, I got the following error:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0xBB572E0E2D182910
gpg: requesting key 2D182910 from hkps server hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

If I correctly understand this error, that means gpg can't trust the CA that emitted the certificate of the key server. To fix this issue, I need to add the certificate of the CA to my list of trusted certificates.

The question is: **how can I get this certificate in a safely manner?** By safe, I mean the certificate can't be compromised by a man-in-the-middle attack, for instance.

Using openssl, I can see the certificate of the key server is signed by `sks-keyservers.net`:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 C = NO, ST = Oslo, O = sks-keyservers.net CA, CN = sks-keyservers.net CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

But how can I trust the certificate given by this command? How can I be sure no attacker falsified the anwser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They publish their [CA certificate](https://sks-keyservers.net/verify_tls.php) on their website. Verify that you are accessing it securely (HTTPS with no errors), then download it. You can also verify its signature and fingerprint (all listed).

They also [have instructions](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php#pool_hkps) to tell `gpg` to use a local CA to verify the connection:

> **hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net**
>
> This is a pool containing only servers
> available using hkps. Regular A and AAAA and SRV records are included
> for port 443 servers, and a lookup is performed for _pgpkey-https._tcp
> on the individual servers to determine if a hkps enabled service is
> listening on another port. At this point, however, servers not running
> on port 443 are not included.
>
> This pool only include servers that have been certified by the
> sks-keyservers.net CA, of which the certificate can be found at
> https://sks-keyservers.net/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem [OpenPGP
> signature] [CRL].
>
> For GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0 installations this can be used by using the
> following parameters in gpg.conf:
>
> ```
> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf:
>   keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net  
>   keyserver-options ca-cert-file=/path/to/CA/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
> ```
>
> GnuPG 2.1 users prior to version 2.1.11 (starting with this version
> the certificate is enabled by default for this pool) want to add the
> following in dirmngr.conf:
>
> ```
> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf:
>    hkp-cacert
>    /path/to/CA/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the alternative instructions just below that block:

> Alternatively you can use instead the WKD to download the key:
>
> wget -O- https://gentoo.org/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/wtktzo4gyuhzu8a4z5fdj3fgmr1u6tob?l=releng | gpg --import

Although, if you have a new enough gpg client, you can simply perform

> gpg --verbose   --locate-key releng@gentoo.org

and it will automatically retrieve the key via WKD.

Since the key is fetched through https:// from gentoo.org, you can be quite sure this is not more malicious than the rest of the instructions you are following.

For the record, the fingerprint of the key I receive this way is `13EB BDBE DE7A 1277 5DFD  B1BA BB57 2E0E 2D18 2910`, in case you want to verify the key you received (and trust the fingerprint I am providing!).